# Assigning (const char *) to function pointer executing a hex code

Tags: c, function, pointers

I found a C code that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char code[] =
"\x31\xd2\xb2\x30\x64\x8b\x12\x8b\x52\x0c\x8b\x52\x1c\x8b\x42"
"\x08\x8b\x72\x20\x8b\x12\x80\x7e\x0c\x33\x75\xf2\x89\xc7\x03"
"\x78\x3c\x8b\x57\x78\x01\xc2\x8b\x7a\x20\x01\xc7\x31\xed\x8b"
"\x34\xaf\x01\xc6\x45\x81\x3e\x46\x61\x74\x61\x75\xf2\x81\x7e"
"\x08\x45\x78\x69\x74\x75\xe9\x8b\x7a\x24\x01\xc7\x66\x8b\x2c"
"\x6f\x8b\x7a\x1c\x01\xc7\x8b\x7c\xaf\xfc\x01\xc7\x68\x72\x6c"
"\x64\x01\x68\x6c\x6f\x57\x6f\x68\x20\x48\x65\x6c\x89\xe1\xfe"
"\x49\x0b\x31\xc0\x51\x50\xff\xd7";

int main(void)
{
    int (*func)();
    func = (int(*)()) code;
    (int)(*func)();
    return 0;
}
```

For the given HEX CODE this program runs well and printing ("HelloWorld"). I was thinking that the HEX CODE is some machine instructions and by calling a function pointer that's pointing to that CODE we are executing that CODE.

Was my thought right? is there something to improve it?

How this HEX CODE gets generated?

Tanks for advance.

Comment: This does not work. It is duff code

Comment: I said a given HEX CODE not `\xFF\xFF\xFF`!

Comment: `code` is stored in the data segment of the process address space. Do these pages have execute permissions? You'll need to set the proper permissions on the relevant pages before you can execute them.

Comment: Why has the question being edited without keeping the original?

Comment: ... And you trying to write a virus?

Comment: @EdHeal The original still in the revision!

Comment: @EdHeal ... And I edited it cause the first comment says it's not working!

Comment: @rullof - It is not - the `code` array seems to have grown without a mention of the original. Anyway why write code that is incomprehensible and IMHO stupid

Comment: The main function is unnecessarily long and clear, it should read: `int main(){((int(*)())code)();}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that by forcing a function pointer like this you are calling into machine instructions written as a hexadecimal string variable.

I doubt that a program like this would work on any CPU since about 2005.

On most RISC CPUs (like ARM) and on all Intel and AMD CPUs that support 64-bit, memory pages have a No Execute bit. Or in reverse an Execute bit.

On memory pages that do not have an Execute bit, the CPU will not run code. Compilers do not put variables into executable memory pages.

In order to run injected shell codes, attackers now have to use "return into libc" or function pointer overwrite attacks which set things up to call mprotect or VirtualProtect to set the execute bit on their shell code. Either that or get it injected into a executable space such as the Java, .NET, or Javascript JIT compiler uses.

Security hardened kernels will deny the ability to call mprotect. Once the program's address space is set by the dynamic library loader, it sets a security flag and no new executable pages can be created.

Comment: There are plenty of modern microcontroller families available without a "no execute" feature. And even more that aren't based on a modern architecture.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make it always work you could assign some executable_readwrite space with malloc or the like and put the code in there and then execute it. Then there won't be any access violation faults.

```
void main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    void* PointerToNewMemoryRegion=0;
    void (*FunctionPointer) ();
    PointerToNewMemoryRegion=VirtualAlloc(RandomPointer,113,MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (PointerToNewMemoryRegion == NULL)
    {
        std::cout<<"Failed to Allocate Memory region Error code: "<<GetLastError();
        return;
    }
    memcpy(PointerToNewMemoryRegion, code,113);
    FunctionPointer = (void(*)()) PointerToNewMemoryRegion;
    (void)(*FunctionPointer) ();


    VirtualFree(PointerToNewMemoryRegion,113,MEM_DECOMMIT)

}
```

but the code never returns to my code to execute so my last line is pointless. So my code has a memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

To ask this question from a "general C" point of view isn't all that meaningful.

First of all, your code has many major problems:

- The literal `"\xFF\xFF\xFF"` equals 0xFFFFFF00, not 0x00FFFFFF as may or may not have been the intention.
- What this hex code means and if it is at all meaningful, is endian-dependent and also depends on the address bus width of the given CPU.
- As others have mentioned, casts between function pointers and regular pointers isn't supported or well-defined by C, the C standard lists it as a "common extension".

That being said, code like this has about one single purpose, and that is various forms of boot loaders and self-updating software used in embedded systems.

Suppose for example that you have a boot loader program that is tasked with re-programming something in the very same segment of flash memory where said program itself is executed from. That is impossible because of the way the memory hardware works. So in order to do so, you would have to execute the actual flash programming routine from RAM. Since the array of hex gibberish is stored in RAM, the program can execute from there with the function pointer trick, assuming that the C compiler has a non-standard extension that allows the cast.

As for how to generate the code, you either write it all in assembler and then translate the assembler instructions to op codes manually (very tedious). Or more likely, you write the function in C and then disassemble it and copy/paste the op codes from the disassembly.

The latter is more dangerous though, as the critical part of getting code like this to work is calling convention: you must be absolutely sure that the function stacks/unstacks things properly when it is called and when it is done, restoring the contents of any CPU registers used etc. Which may force you to write part of the function in assembler anyhow. Needless to say, the code will be completely non-portable.

Comment: If I were writing something like that, I think it'd be better to compile it into a separate .o file and use linker commands to give it the correct names. For example, if you needed to copy it into RAM to execute it you could define a symbol at the end of the function and use memcpy(dest, func, func_end-func).